# Find minimum value in multiple column range with criteria

Tags: excel, min

How can I find the minimum value in columns B:C in the table below if the volume is <= 10.

**The expected result is in yellow.**

[image: mytable]

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Search Google for MIN IF array formulae

Comment: I have tried the formula in this [link] https://exceljet.net/formula/minimum-value-if but it des not work in multiple column range.

Comment: Try nesting more than one IF for each column

Comment: Jonathan, suppose that you have 20 columns range. How can I do it?

Comment: why is the answer 22. shouldn't it be 20(`B7`) if you want the minimum value in the range `B2:C7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

`=AGGREGATE(15,6,C2:C9/(A2:B9<=10),1)`

or, **array formula****:

`=MIN(IF(A2:B9<=10,C2:C9))`

If there may be blank cells in `B2:C9`:

`=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/C2:C9)/(A2:B9<=10),1)`

or:

`=MIN(IF(A2:B9<=10,IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C9),C2:C9)))`

Regards

Comment: It works just fine, thanks. Now let me ask one more thing, suppose that you have a blank cell in the lowest volume number. I tried this formula and it works `{=IF(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9<=10;$B$2:$C$9);1)>0;SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9<=10;$B$2:$C$9);1);SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9<=10;$B$2:$C$9);2))}`. What is your opinion?

Comment: Sorry? Blank cell in which column(s)?

Comment: I need the formula to retrieve the lowest value greater than 0 from columns B:C when the lowest value in column A is matched. You may have multiple blank cells in columns B and C. The formula that I wrote above, just gives me the second lowest, but if I have many blank cells, it does not gives the result I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to get the minimum value (Which according to me should be 20 in your data set)

```
=MIN(1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((A2:A9<=10)*B2:B9),1),1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((A2:A9<=10)*C2:C9),1))
```

for each additional column(say `D`) you will have to add the formula `1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((A2:A9<=10)*D2:D9),1)` inside the `MIN()` formula.

Looking for a better way to do this.

**EDIT:**

Alternatively you could add a new row below your data. for each column you add the below formula to get the min for that column

```
=1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(($A$2:$A$9<=10)*B2:B9),1)
```

Now you can drag this formula to as many columns you want. Take the `MIN()` of this row to get the overall minimum.

Comment: You can pass a 2D range to AGGREGATE: =AGGREGATE(15,6,C2:C9/(A2:B9<=10),1)

Comment: @XORLX but op wants to compare values whose corresponding value in the volume column is less than 10. Hence I used only `A2:A9`

Comment: You are right, my result should be 20. Sorry, my mistake!