# Can I use MINIFS or INDEX/MATCH on two non-contiguous ranges...?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, min

Problem is straightforward, but solution is escaping.  Hopefully some master here can provide insight.

I have a big data grid with prices.  Those prices are ordered by location (rows) and business name (cols).  I need to match the location/row by looking at two criteria (location name and a second column).  Once the matching row is found (there will always be a match), I need to get the minimum/lowest price from two ranges within the grid.

The last point is the real challenge.  Unlike a normal INDEX or MINIFS scenario, the columns I need to MIN aren't contiguous... for example, I need to know what the MIN value is between I4:J1331 and Q4:U1331.  It's not an intersection, it's a contiguous set of values across two different arrays.

You're probably saying "hey, why don't you just reorder your table to make them contiguous"... not an option.  I have a lot of data, and this spreadsheet is used for a bunch of other stuff.  So, I have to work with the format I have, and that means figuring out how to do a lookup/min across multiple non-contiguous ranges.  My latest attempt:

```
=MINIFS(AND($I$4:$J$1331,$K$4:$P$1331),$B$4:$B$1331,$A2,$E$4:$E$1331,$B2)
```

Didn't work, but it should make it more clear what I'm trying to do.  There has GOT to be an easy way to just tell excel "use these two ranges instead of one".

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Is this [same scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104063/find-minimum-value-in-multiple-column-range-with-criteria)?

Comment: No.  In the scenario you linked to the range being tested for MIN is contiguous... meaning next to each other/touching (B:C).  Findings MINs or working with ranges is fairly straighforward when they are in one lump group.  My problem was that I had to search across two ranges that weren't touching... e.g., find the MIN based on matching criteria within/across cols C:F and P:S.  Excel doesn't have an easy way to create a super array comprised of multiple smaller arrays (like my MINIF example above, where I tried to AND() two arrays together.

Comment: Got it. if you managed to solve your own question and it works, [mark it with the check mark at the left of it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) (just wait 48 hours to do it).It'll help others find it too.

Comment: Thx, will do.  Says I have to wait 22 hours... I'm not good with stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  For anyone else who's interested, there doesn't seem to be any easy way to just "AND" arrays together for a search (Hello MS, backlog please).  So, what I did instead was to just create multiple INDEX/MATCH arrays inside of a MIN function and take the result.  Like this:

MIN((INDEX/MATCH ARRAY 1),(INDEX/MATCH ARRAY 2))

They both have identical criteria, the only difference is the set of arrays being indexed in each function.  That basically gives me this:

MIN((match array),(match array))

And Min can then pull the lowest value from either.

Not as elegant as I'd like... lots of redundant code, but at least it works.

-rt

Comment: I should note, that to return an index/match array you need to 1) set the col target to 0 and 2) enter the formula with ctrl+shft+return (standard index/match behavior)